# How can I make sure that the function inside 'for loop' gets executed before I send the response in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am using bluebird for this. I need to get this function i.e. get_like_status(email, results[i].id) which is at the end of the for loop to execute before I send the headers. I get it undefined when I console the array list. I would appreciate it enormously if you can do it using bluebird however I am open to any other packages for promises.

```
var list = new Array();
  console.log(results.length);
  function get_like_status(email, project_id){
    connection.query("SELECT email FROM likes WHERE liked_by='"+email+"' AND project_id='"+project_id+"';", function(err, results, fields){
      if(err){console.log(err); return(err)}else{
        if(results.length > 0){
          console.log("yes");
          return "yes";
        }else{
          console.log("yes");
          return "no";
        }
      }

    })
  }
  for(var i=0; i < results.length; i++){
    var empty = new Array();
    list.push(empty);
    list[i].push(results[i].email);
    list[i].push(results[i].project_name);
    list[i].push(results[i].project_description);
    list[i].push(results[i].header_image);
    list[i].push(results[i].id);
    list[i].push(get_like_status(email, results[i].id)); // This gets executed after the program has sent response!
  }
  Promise.all(list).then(function(){
    console.log(list);
    res.send(list); });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to refactor your code to actually wait for the promises, right now the `list` array is just a regular array with different values, it's not an array of promises waiting to be resolved.

Something similar to this

```
function get_like_status(email, project_id) {
    return new Promise(function( res, rej ) {
        var query = "SELECT email FROM likes WHERE liked_by='" + 
                    email + "' AND project_id='" + project_id + "';"

        connection.query(query, function(err, results, fields) {
            if (err) {
                rej(err);
            } else {
                res( results.length > 0 ? "yes" : "no" );
            }
        });
    });
}

var promises = [];
var list = results.map(function(item, index) {
    var arr = [
        item.email,
        item.project_name,
        item.project_description,
        item.header_image,
        item.id
    ]
    promises.push( 
        get_like_status(item.email, item.id).then(function(res) { 
            arr.push(res);
            return arr;
        }) 
    );
})

Promise.all( promises ).then(function() {
    res.send(list);
}).catch(function( err ) {
    res.send('epic fail!')
})
```

Note that if `connection.query` returns a promise, there's no need to wrap it in another promise, it's just not clear where `connection.query` is coming from?

Comment: Ok. That was great. It really worked well for me. However I had to change code little bit since my logic was different but you made it pretty clear in the answer that you were just explaining idea behind using promises in loops.